# jQuery mobile nested-list plugin bug going back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, nested-lists

I'm using the 'nested-list' plugin for jQuery Mobile, [this one](https://rawgit.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-nestedlists/master/jquery.mobile.nestedlists.js):

The problem is that when you use more than one level the plugins fails going back. For example, in the fiddle I have created I can go to `'Test 1.2.1'` without problem, If I going back 1 level it works fine and I go to `'Test 1.2'`, but then if I tried to go up one level more (it was `'Test1'`) it goes up 2 levels (to `'Test'`).

I have checked the plugin code but I can't find the problem and I have left a message in the Git forum with no answer. Maybe someone could help me here.

Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9v3y/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the plugin code, it is only designed for one level deep nesting. This is because the developer chose to remove created subpages each time you click on a parent LI.  So when you get to the second level of depth, its parent has been removed from the DOM and you have to click the back button twice to get to the original page.

I have made some changes to the plugin code that should solve this problem:

In _attachBindings, I have commented out the line that removes previously created subpages:

```
_attachBindings: function() {
    this._on({
        "click": "_handleSubpageClick"
    });
    this._on( "body", {
        "pagechange": function(){
            if ( this.opening === true ) {
                this.open = true;
                this.opening = false;
            } else if ( this.open === true ) {
                //Don't remove the old LI
                //this.newPage.remove();
                this.open = false;
            }
        }
    });
},...
```

Then in _handleSubpageClick, I check if the subpage already exists in the DOM (via data attribute added when creating the page). If not, we go through the existing code that creates the subpage, and then in the end I store the created subpage id in a data attribute on the parent LI. If it does exist we just navigate to that page.

```
_handleSubpageClick: function( event ) {
    if( $(event.target).closest( "li" ).children( "ul" ).length == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    this.opening = true;
    //see if we already created the subpage
    var $li = $(event.target).closest( "li" );
    var pid = $li.data("nextpageid");
    if (pid && pid.length > 0){
        this.pageID = pid;
    } else {
        this.newPage = $( this.options.page ).uniqueId();
        this.nestedList  = $( event.target ).children( "ul" )
            .clone().attr( "data-" + $.mobile.ns + "role", "listview" )
            .css( "display", "block" );
        this.pageName = (
            $( event.target.childNodes[0] ).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length > 0 )?
            $( event.target.childNodes[0] ).text() : $( event.target.childNodes[1] ).text();
        this.pageID = this.newPage.attr( "id" );

        // Build new page
        this.newPage.append(
            $( this.options.header ).find( "h1" ).text( this.pageName ).end()
        ).append(
            $( this.options.content )
        ).find( "div.ui-content" ).append( this.nestedList );

        $( "body" ).append( this.newPage );
        //save subpage id as data attribute of the LI
        $li.data("nextpageid", this.pageID);
    }


    $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + this.pageID );
}...
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3RC9L/)**

I removed the external link to the plugin and instead copied all the code into the javascript pane and made the edits.  You should be able to copy that code directly and use as the updated plugin. (Of course I did this quickly and have not rigorously tested it, so make sure it works for you).

Comment: Amazing, man. Seriously, thank you very much!! it works perfectly and the explanation is very useful.

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to publish this in the Github forum @ezanker

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53, you are welcome. Go ahead and publish at Github and let us know if the developer comes up with a better 'fix'